# How to Pass Id Here (error put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request') In form template Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, django-tagging

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "poll"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),  # listing the polls
    path('<int:id>/edit/', views.put, name='poll_edit'), ]
```

views.py

```
def put(self, request, id):
    # print("catching error ")  error before this line
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=id)
    poll_form = PollForm(request.POST, instance=question)
    choice_forms = [ChoiceForm(request.POST, prefix=str(
        choice.id), instance=choice) for choice in question.choice_set.all()]
    if poll_form.is_valid() and all([cf.is_valid() for cf in choice_form]):
        new_poll = poll_form.save(commit=False)
        new_poll.created_by = request.user
        new_poll.save()
        for cf in choice_form:
            new_choice = cf.save(commit=False)
            new_choice.question = new_poll
            new_choice.save()
        return redirect('poll:index')
    context = {'poll_form': poll_form, 'choice_forms': choice_forms}
    return render(request, 'polls/edit_poll.html', context)
```

edit_poll.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="PUT" >
    {% csrf_token %}
<table class="table table-bordered table-light">

    {{poll_form.as_table}}
    
    {% for form in choice_forms %}
         {{form.as_table}}
    {% endfor %}
    
    
</table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning float-right">Update</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

this is error

```
line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /polls/9/edit/
Exception Value: put() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

I know that I am not passing argument in html but i dont know how to pass id argument in html please help me
any single line of code something like default (context passing by Django)

Comment: Remove the `self` parameter. THis is for class members. Here you are defining a function.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem I am facing another error 
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed 
it was worked fine Do you know what this means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a simple function, not a method in a class, you thus should remove the `self` parameter:

```
# no self ↓
def put(request, id):
    # …
```

Note that what you are doing with the `choice_forms` is basically what a [**`FormSet`** does [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/).